# object in D^bCoh(P^2) with prescribed RHom's

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, coherent-sheaves

Let $\mathbb{C}P^2$ denote the projective plane.

From reading the section of http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~coskun/gokova.pdf
which surveys Gieseker stable sheaves, I have understood that there are no Gieseker stable   bundles $E$ with

$\operatorname{Hom}(E,E)=\mathbb{C}$,
$\operatorname{Ext}^1(E,E)=\mathbb{C}$,
$\operatorname{Ext}^{\neq 0,1}(E,E)=0$

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. Is there an object $E$ in $\operatorname{D^bCoh}(\mathbb{C}P^2)$ with

$\operatorname{Hom}^0(E,E)=\mathbb{C}$,
$\operatorname{Hom}^1(E,E)=\mathbb{C}$,
$\operatorname{Hom}^{\neq 0,1}(E,E)=0$